# Can I combine two universities in the Stack Overflow developer story data source?

Tags: support, bug, developer-story

Right now there are two different universities that pop up when I enter my school's name.

What is the source of this data? Is there any way I can merge them?

Example with Eckerd College:
[image: An auto-complete dropdown that shows two results with the same name but different logos.]

Comment: Now [there are 3 entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koFbi.png)...